# Unable to read input logs filebeat

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, centos7, filebeat

I am fairly new to docker and I am trying out the ELK Setup with Filebeat. I have a container for filebeat setup in machine 1 and I am trying to collect the logs from `/mnt/logs/temp.log` (which are non-container logs) to the ELK containers in machine 2. Here's my filebeat configuration:-

```
filebeat.config:
  modules:
    path: ${path.config}/modules.d/*.yml
    reload.enabled: false

filebeat.autodiscover:
  providers:
    - type: docker
      hints.enabled: true
      hints.default_config:
        type: container
        paths:
          - /mnt/logs/temp.log

processors:
- add_cloud_metadata: ~

output.elasticsearch:
  hosts: '${ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS:42.23.12.131:9042}'
```

Even if I change the filebeat.yml config to the below, it doesn't seem to send any logs to ES:-

```
filebeat.inputs:
- type: log
  paths:
    - /mnt/logs/temp.log

output.elasticsearch:
  hosts: ["42.23.12.131:9042"]
```

Can someone please help me out or point me to any site articles or documentation regarding this? Version of filebeat and ELK container is 7.14.0.

Edit: The docker-compose file for ELK is:-

```
version: '2.2'

services:
  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.14.0
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ./elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml
        target: /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml
        read_only: true
      - type: volume
        source: elasticsearch
        target: /usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    environment:
      ES_JAVA_OPTS: "-Xmx512m -Xms512m"
      discovery.type: single-node
    ports:
      - "9200:9200"
      - "9300:9300"
    networks:
      - elk

  logstash:
    image: docker.elastic.co/logstash/logstash:7.14.0
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ./logstash/config/logstash.yml
        target: /usr/share/logstash/config/logstash.yml
        read_only: true
      - type: bind
        source: ./logstash/pipeline.conf
        target: /usr/share/logstash/pipeline.conf
        read_only: true
    ports:
      - "5044:5044/udp"
      - "9600:9600"
    environment:
      LS_JAVA_OPTS: "-Xmx512m -Xms512m"
    networks:
      - elk
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch

  kibana:
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:7.14.0
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ./kibana/kibana.yml
        target: /usr/share/kibana/config/kibana.yml
        read_only: true
    ports:
      - "5601:5601"
    networks:
      - elk
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch

networks:
  elk:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  elasticsearch:
```

Comment: the host 1 and host 2  with docker-compose configuration file or in other way ?

Comment: @YLR host2 i.e. the elk stack is setup by using docker-compose whereas host1 i.e. the filebeat container is setup by following this article:- https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/running-on-docker.html

Comment: Ok, so could you send our docker-compose file on your question, it looks like host1 (FB 1) can't seen elastic outside the docker-compose stack

Comment: @YLR Added in the main post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your docker-compose file, juste this ports are exposed outside the container (in consideration, the port 9042 is the one you have configured on elasticsearch side) :

> ```
> ports:
>   - "9200:9200"
>   - "9300:9300"
> ```

So, if you add the targeted port *9042*, it must work. So this must looks like this :

> ```
> ports:
>   - "9200:9200"
>   - "9300:9300"
>   - "9042:9042"
> ```

If is not the port *9042* that you have configured into your elasticsearhc, that means you have to change the configuration from your filebeat agent to have the correct port (probably the *9200*)